# How to display component in angular 2?

Tags: angular

Just starting with angular 2 using the angular2-seed app: https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed. I have created a component but it wont display on the page,this component sits in a directory called external_components at the same level as components:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'SiteQualification',
  template: '<div>hello service external</div>',
})
export class SiteQualification {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

This is the seed-app.ts:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
//import {Router, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
import {SiteQualification} from './external_components/sitequalification';
import {RepoBrowser} from './components/repo-browser/repo-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'seed-app',
    providers: [],
    pipes: [],

    templateUrl: 'app/seed-app.html',
})

export class SeedApp {

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

In the seed-app.html I have:

```
<main>
    <siteQualification></siteQualification>
</main>
```

This is app.ts:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {SeedApp} from './app/seed-app';


bootstrap(SeedApp, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
])
.catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Also removed the router.
The problem is the component won't display? What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a console error? Are you bootstrapping your main app?

Comment: Selector is `SiteQualification`, tag is `siteQualification`. That isn't the issue?

Comment: @echonax there is no console error

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Tried does not fix it : (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to list components and directives in the `directives: [...]` list of the component where they are used:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'seed-app',
    directives: [SiteQualification],
    ...
})
```